# Python Script Failing to Open Firefox.lnk file on Desktop Path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, firefox, pyautogui

TLDR; I have a python script that uses `autopygui` to click on a file and open it, but it does not work with `lnk` files located in the same path.

I have a little script using `pyautogui` to screenshot a desktop icon and save it as a png image on the desktop and `doubleclick` it to open that image. This works perfect.

However..

I tried implementing the same script on an existing `Firefox.lnk` shortcut and it fails with the following error:

[locateOnScreen Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThvM4.png)

Things I have tried:

1. Running VS code as admin.
2. `locateOnCenterScreen` and `locateOnScreen`.
3. I have tried others, but I'm blanking because I have tried everything I can think of.

It should open my Firefox.lnk shortcut up, it does not. It only works on png file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `locateOnScreen(...)` function only accepts paths to image files, and .lnk files are not image files.  If you manually took a screenshot of the Firefox icon on your desktop, saved it as a PNG file, and passed that to your script, it would open fine.

If you want to launch a program using a .lnk file from Python, you don't need pyautogui at all.  Consider using `os.startfile(...)` instead.

Comment: Hey @wallefan thanks for the reply. This makes sense, I missed this in the documentation when I was reading. Bad question on my part for missing it in the documentation.

I have resorted to using pywinauto and it also seems to be a viable option for the task at hand, however not sure how well it works. 

Nevertheless, thank you. Will upvote asap.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the path of png file in `locateCenterOnScreen(...)` function instead.

Please also make sure you minimize all active windows so that pyautogui could locate your Firefox short icon.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('winleft','d')
icon_location = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('.../FireFox_icon_screenshot.png', confidence=0.9)
pyautogui.moveTo(icon_location)
pyautogui.click(clicks=2)
```